# How do I return multiple "documents" from a web forms application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, crystal-reports, webforms

We have a webforms application that generates parametric documents. The user supplies some information, clicks a button, and our web service generates Word documents.

The service works for one document at a time but not batches. We want to add the ability to process more than one document. We now have the code below, where contactIdsForLetters is a `List<int>`.

```
foreach (int contactId in contactIdsForLetters)
{
    string parameters = string.Format("ContactID~{0}", contactId);

    string defaultFilename = Reporting.Utilities.CreateDefaultFileName(outputformat);

    byte[] bytes = Reporting.Reports.CreateReport(selectedReportId, parameters, outputformat, out serviceCallWasSuccessful);

    if (!serviceCallWasSuccessful || bytes == null)
    {
        Reporting.Reports.LogReportActivity(selectedReportId, string.Empty, parameters, userLogin, false);

        return;
    }

    Reporting.Reports.LogReportActivity(selectedReportId, string.Empty, parameters, userLogin, true);

    Reporting.Utilities.SendResponse(defaultFilename, bytes);
}
```

When running the above code, only one document is ever returned. One document is processed (the `For-Each` never gets to the second item in `contactIdsForLetters`), a dialog pops up asking to open or save the file, and after clicking open, Word opens with the document. Everything is happening like it should but we can't get the `For-Each` to process the second and subsequent documents.

The users want a seperate Word session for each document returned. Subsequent documents will need to open in their own Word session.

How do I loop through a `List<int>`, send each `int` to a service one-at-a-time, and open a Word session for each returned document?

Here is SendResponse() ...

```
public static void SendResponse(string defaultFilename, byte[] bytes)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", defaultFilename));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Please tell us where the web service is? Also, is this an ASMX service or WCF? "Add Service Reference" or "Add Web Reference"? Can you show us the signatures of the service operations you are calling?

Comment: @John Saunders - This is a WCF service, Reporting.Reports.CreateReport(string, string, Crystal Reports ExportFormatType (enum), out bool)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem sending a `List<int>` to the service and having the service return `List<byte[]>`.

I don't know what you mean by "open a Word session". I hope you're not trying to call Word from an ASP.NET application. That's not supported, is unreliable, and doesn't work very well.

Comment: The SendResponse() sends the bytes to the client. The user then decides to open or save the document. The behavior is like opening a PDF on the web. If the list contains three ints, we want three documents returned (one for each int)

Comment: I'm confused. How much of this is working now? This doesn't seem like it's a WCF service. It sounds like a web application. Does SendResponse use Response.WriteFile or something?

Comment: It all works now (as long as you pass one int, not a batch). The webforms app calls the WCF service. SendResponse() is a method that sets the headers (Content-Disposition, Content-Length, etc.) and then does a BinaryWrite, flush, and end.

Comment: I'm missing something basic here. What are you trying to do? Is your problem that you can't get multiple documents from a single service call, or that you can't return multiple documents to the user at his browser?

Comment: The service is working fine. Each service call should return one document. The problem is when looping over the List<int> only the first contact ever gets a document. After it runs, the line Reporting.Utilities.SendResponse(defaultFilename, bytes) exits the For-Each loop instead of going back to the top of the For-Each to process the next item in List<int>.

Comment: Have you debugged through the code? Is there an exception? Is `bytes` being returned as `null`?

Comment: I have stepped through the code. After SendResponse(), the loop exits gracefully, albeit not as desired or expected. Individually, each int works fine and each int gets a document from the service. No nulls. No exceptions.

Comment: I think you'd better step into SendResponse. That loop is not exiting gracefully. Does it get back to the top, to see if there's another int available? I bet this has to do with SendResponse using Response.End or something like that.

Comment: No, stepping through the loop I do not get back to the top to see if there are other items in the list. I've included the code for SendResponse() above. I removed the Response.End line but then the dialog asking to open / save the file just hangs.

Comment: You have discovered your problem. It has nothing to do with web services. Your problem is that it's not possible to return multiple documents from an ASP.NET application back to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET runs on top HTTP.

HTTP is based on a per request basis.

Each request returns a response if the browser is able to reach the server.
This response contains a stream (we can call it File in your case).
After the server flushes that stream (1st file) the request connection to the server is closed and the request life cycle ends, closing any threads related to that request.
This is why you never get to the second document.

You are going to have to deliver the documents in a compressed container like a zip file so all the documents go in a single stream. First get all the documents, package them and send the response to the client.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** Also you might want to look at using AJAX to generate a javascript call to the server returning different links to pull the different documents. It would be like clicking on different invisible links that open different documents after the user clicks a single button or link. Using this approach is really easy to achieve what you want. You can trigger the click event for all the invisible links with javascript.